# clickOnce, .application fail: The network path was not found

Tags: c#, clickonce, visual-studio-2013

I am attempting to set up a clickOnce application on a shared server. I have set borth the publishing location and installation folder to point at the same location:
Z:\HRd Utility\
and
\\Z\hrd utility\

however when running the app from the Z folder it gives me the following error.

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.18052
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.18052 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///Z:/HRd%20Utility/Application%20Files/MainLauncher_1_0_0_7/MainLauncher.application
    Deployment Provider url     : file://z/hrd%20utility/MainLauncher.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of Z:\HRd Utility\Application Files\MainLauncher_1_0_0_7\MainLauncher.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading file://z/hrd utility/MainLauncher.application did not succeed.
        + The network path was not found.

        + The network path was not found.

        + The network path was not found.


COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [7/18/2013 11:28:13 AM] : Activation of Z:\HRd Utility\Application Files\MainLauncher_1_0_0_7\MainLauncher.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [7/18/2013 11:28:13 AM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading file://z/hrd utility/MainLauncher.application did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifest(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ManifestType manifestType, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirect(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.FollowDeploymentProviderUri(SubscriptionStore subStore, AssemblyManifest& deployment, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - The network path was not found.

        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - The network path was not found.

        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.IO.IOException
        - The network path was not found.

        - Source: mscorlib
        - Stack trace:
            at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
            at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync)
            at System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)


  Not sure why it isn't allowing it to install.
```

Comment: Dont use a mapped drive letter "Z:" for the install path, use a server name or IP address.

Answer (score 0):

For whomever may follow:

I just lost 15 minutes on this problem

It was all on my local machine 'rocket'

I hade a share called '\rocket\Swap' that I was testing with, but I'd published to a share called '\rocket\Share'

VS2019 was even telling me that it couldn't open the published share.

In summary: check that you can open the share that's specified in your click once manifest.